# Is the INFO log in API Manager written also to log file or command line only?

Tags: logging, wso2-api-manager

I need to cath events in WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0. and I like INFO level log for this. But I am not sure if this level is written to log file too and where or only to command line as mentioned here

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging/

INFO    Indicates important runtime events, such as server startup/shutdown. These logs are expected to be immediately visible on the command line that you used for starting the server . It is recommended to keep these logs to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

INFO logs are also written to a log file and rolled over based on the time (daily). The log files are created with the name "**wso2carbon-xx-xx-xxxx.log**" inside **/wso2am-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT/repository/logs/** directory.